# How do I get the image stored on a server to be viewed properly in my browser?

Tags: php, mysql, image, filepath

With what i have done so far, I can upload an image to a folder and save the name in the database. What i am trying to do is to be able to view each image in a browser with the corresponding name besides or under it. But what i have is the wrong image assigned a wrong name. The first image in my browser is assigned the next two names in the records in the database. What am i doing wrong? Please I need help.

Here are my codes:

**ADD Page:-**

```
    <table width="760" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td height="100" align="center" bgcolor="#CC0000" class="header_title">Facilitators Panel
          <table width="600" height="30" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="448" class="header_title" height="20"></td>
              <td width="92" class="text2"><a href="cpanel.php?user=<?php echo $row_rsadmin['aID']; ?>">Control Panel</a></td>
              <td width="60" class="text2">Logout</td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="300" valign="top" bgcolor="#666666" class="text2"><table width="640" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text2"><a href="adfacilitators.php?user=<?php echo $row_rsadmin['aID']; ?>">Back</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="text2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          <table width="640" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="640" height="40" colspan="4" align="center"><form action="fac.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="fac" id="fac">
      <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td height="1" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="132" align="right" class="text3">Name:</td>
          <td width="10" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2"><label>
            <input name="name" type="text" class="textbox" id="name" />
          </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="45" align="right"><p class="text3">Photo:</p></td>
          <td width="272" height="45"><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="256000" />
            <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo" size="26" /></td>
          <td width="166">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="1" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="40" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" valign="top"><label>
            <input name="button" type="submit" class="readmore" id="button" value="Submit" />
          </label>
            <input name="button2" type="reset" class="readmore" id="button2" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="10" colspan="4" align="center"></td>
          </tr>
          </table></p></td></tr>
    </table>
```

**Processing Page:-**

```
    <?php require("../Connections/connMain.php"); ?>
    <?php

                // validation... since this is an image upload script we should run a check   
                // to make sure the uploaded file is in fact an image. Here is a simple check: 
                // getimagesize() returns false if the file tested is not an image. 
                if ($image = @getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])&& ($_FILES["photo"]["size"]<= 2560000))
                {}
                else
                {
                    header("Location:error1.php");

                exit;
                }


       //This gets all the other information from the form 
      $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
      $pix= ($_FILES['photo']['name']);
      $tmpName = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']; 


     //Writes the information to the database 
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO facilitators (photo, name) VALUES ('$pix', '$name')"); 


     //This is the directory where images will be saved 
     // Make sure the file was sent without errors
     //if($_FILES['photo']['error'] == 0) {
     $target = "../facilitators/";

     $target = $target  . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 


     //Writes the photo to the server 
     if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $target)) 
     { 

     header("Location:adfacilitators.php");

     }
     else { 

     header("Location:error2.php");

     }
    ?>
```

**OutPut Page:**

```
<div id="wrapper2">
    <div id="headercont"><?php require_once('header.html'); ?></div>
    <div id="bannercont"><?php require_once('banner.html'); ?></div>
    <div id="mainbody">
      <div id="sidelink"><?php require_once('sidelink.html'); ?></div>
        <div id="mainbodyr">
          <div class="clear_4"></div>
          <div id="subheadertext">Facilitators</div>
          <div class="clear_4"></div>
          <div id="mainbodycontentcont">
            <?php do { ?>
            <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="150"><div id="mainbodypiccont">
                  <? $info = mysql_fetch_array( $rsFacilitator ); echo "<img src=http://localhost/youngatart/facilitators/".$info['photo'] ." width='150'>" ?>
                </div></td>
                <td width="370"><div id="mainbodytextcont">
                  <div id="text1"><?php echo $row_rsFacilitator['name']; ?></div>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="20" colspan="2"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
              <?php } while ($row_rsFacilitator = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFacilitator)); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear_5"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: have you check database. Is data is inserting fine ???????????

Comment: data is inserting fine and pic is uploaded to folder on server. What i need is to be able to output the data and its corresponding image on a line based on its id in the database, such that i can later edit each item name based on its id and the photo as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, I have changed your code a bit,

```
<div id="mainbodycontentcont">
            <?php while ($row_rsFacilitator = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFacilitator) { ?>
            <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="150"><div id="mainbodypiccont">
                  <? echo "<img src=http://localhost/youngatart/facilitators/".$row_rsFacilitator['photo'] ." width='150'>" ?>
                </div></td>
                <td width="370"><div id="mainbodytextcont">
                  <div id="text1"><?php echo $row_rsFacilitator['name']; ?></div>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="20" colspan="2"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
              <?php }?>
          </div>
```

***EDIT***
i did not exactly understand your question but if you want to edit your data from image click just give `<a>` tag to image.

```
<div id="mainbodycontentcont">
                <?php while ($row_rsFacilitator = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFacilitator)) { ?>
                <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="150"><div id="mainbodypiccont">
                      <? echo "<a href='yourfilename.php?imageid=1'><img src=http://localhost/youngatart/facilitators/".$row_rsFacilitator['photo'] ." width='150'></a>" ?>
                    </div></td>
                    <td width="370"><div id="mainbodytextcont">
                      <div id="text1"><a href='yourfilename.php?imageid=1'><?php echo $row_rsFacilitator['name']; ?></a></div>
                    </div></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="20" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                  <?php }?>
              </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But i am having a syntax error on the second line of your code ( <?php while ($row_rsFacilitator = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsFacilitator) { ?> )

Comment: just saw what the problem was. The line of code was missing a closed bracket.

Comment: Thanks A lot. you have been of tremendous help. It is working fine now. To go a bit further, if i want to be able to edit each entry by clicking a link that takes me to a page with a form that is bounded to each form element say the text field is bound to the name field in the database and the file field is bound to the photo field of the datatbase, then i can edit the name and picture of that particular entry as well being able to delete as well. I can do al that with text alone but not with the image. Any help please

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael i have edited my code.. i could not understand your question though , but if this is not what you are looking for tell me

Comment: Thanks for all your help. what i am hoping to do, is to have an edit link besides each name that when i click it, it takes me to a page with a form that has a text field, file field and edit button. The form fields, i presume should have their value from the database table based on the id passed from the specific table item.  below the code for the form:

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael did you check my edited answer i have added a <a> tag besides image, and it is passing the id of image, i think it will work correctly

Comment: @AgbogidiMichael your input type "file" contains value which is not allowed. you will have to show your image using <img src="filename.jpg"/> and if you want to delete that image, <a href="filedelete.php?imageid=1"><img src="filename.jpg"/></a>.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and patience. Yes i have looked at the code. The first page which you helped me out with, is the page the viewers are supposed to see. Now this page is the page that the administrator sees. It has with each record, a link to an update page. This page has a form which has its form elements bound to the table fields in the database. The idea is that from the admin end, i should be able to update the name and image of whichever entry i click the edit link on through the form. And have the field updated in the database. will put the code for the update page below

Comment: '<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="1" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="132" align="right" class="text3">Name:</td>
                      <td width="10" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td colspan="2"><label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="textbox" id="name" value="<?php echo $row_rsfacilitators['name']; ?>" />
                      </label></td>
                    </tr>'

Comment: <tr>
                      <td height="45" align="right"><p class="text3">Photo:</p></td>
                      <td width="272" height="45"><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2560000" />
                        <input name="photo" type="file" id="photo" value="<?php echo $row_rsfacilitators['photo']; ?>" size="26" /></td>
                      <td width="166"><input name="hiddenfacID" type="hidden" id="hiddenfacID" value="<?php echo $row_rsfacilitators['facID']; ?>" /></td>
                    </tr>

Comment: <tr>
                      <td height="40" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td colspan="2" valign="top"><label>
                        <input name="button" type="submit" class="readmore" id="button" value="Edit" />
                      </label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

Comment: I cant seem to get it to come out on this forum as code form.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have been able to resolve the issues i had. I have even gone futher to learn a thing or two. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well seen your code, you've inserted record first and then you've uploaded the file. Try doing it reverse. First upload the file. If successful, assign picture name to the variable `$pix` Then do inserting stuff in the database. And check if in the folder if file is successfully uploaded in the directory. Try to match the name of this file with one just inserted in the database.

Moreover, A little Note:

- Avoid using deprecated `mysql_` functions, go for `mysqli_` or PDO.
- Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks also for the input. I switched and uploaded image to server before input to database. It helped solved the overwriting of images with the same name. I also added the rand() and time() function to uniquely identify each image.